# why ConcurrentHashMap doesn't use 'CAS' but use 'synchronized' when tabAt[i] is not null

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

```
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
if (key == null || value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
int hash = spread(key.hashCode());
int binCount = 0;
for (Node<K,V>[] tab = table;;) {
    Node<K,V> f; int n, i, fh;
    if (tab == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
        tab = initTable();
    else if ((f = tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash)) == null) {
        if (casTabAt(tab, i, null,
                     new Node<K,V>(hash, key, value, null)))
            break;                   // no lock when adding to empty bin
    }
    else if ((fh = f.hash) == MOVED)
        tab = helpTransfer(tab, f);
    else {
        V oldVal = null;
        synchronized (f) {
            if (tabAt(tab, i) == f) {
                if (fh >= 0) {
                    binCount = 1;
                    for (Node<K,V> e = f;; ++binCount) {
                        K ek;
                        if (e.hash == hash &&
                            ((ek = e.key) == key ||
                             (ek != null && key.equals(ek)))) {
                            oldVal = e.val;
                            if (!onlyIfAbsent)
                                e.val = value;
                            break;
                        }
                        Node<K,V> pred = e;
                        if ((e = e.next) == null) {
                            pred.next = new Node<K,V>(hash, key,
                                                      value, null);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (f instanceof TreeBin) {
                    Node<K,V> p;
                    binCount = 2;
                    if ((p = ((TreeBin<K,V>)f).putTreeVal(hash, key,
                                                   value)) != null) {
                        oldVal = p.val;
                        if (!onlyIfAbsent)
                            p.val = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (binCount != 0) {
            if (binCount >= TREEIFY_THRESHOLD)
                treeifyBin(tab, i);
            if (oldVal != null)
                return oldVal;
            break;
        }
    }
}
addCount(1L, binCount);
return null;
```

}

When `tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash))` is `null`, it use CAS to add/modify a node, but when is not null, it use `synchronized (f)`. I think it can still use CAS of last node or node with key that need put of `tabAt(tab, i = (n - 1) & hash))` to add/modify a node. But why not? My idea is wrong.

Comment: If `f` exists, then it is going to traverse and modify a tree or list data structure. That cannot be done atomically in-place, so they would need to either do a copy-on-write on the whole thing (and the CAS at the end could result in having to do it all over again in the face of concurreny), or lock the whole structure down with a synchronized block.

Comment: Can you post a link to the source? These things change between JDK versions.